# How to resolve npm dependency and can't import named export 'Component' from non EcmaScript module during react-konva installation?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am facing issues during installation of react-konva using npm.

Firstly the `npm install react-konva --save` gave me below error:

```
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@">=18.0.0" from react-konva@18.2.2
npm WARN   node_modules/react-konva
npm WARN     react-konva@"*" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-konva@18.2.2
npm WARN Found: react-dom@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^16.8.0" from @material-ui/core@4.11.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm WARN     @material-ui/core@"^4.11.1" from the root project
npm WARN   10 more (@material-ui/styles, @material-ui/system, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@">=18.0.0" from react-konva@18.2.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-konva
npm WARN   react-konva@"*" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@">=18.0.0" from react-konva@18.2.2
npm WARN   node_modules/react-konva
npm WARN     react-konva@"*" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
```

After that I tried with --force , it somehow got installed, but getting below error while trying to launch my react application :

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/react-konva/node_modules/its-fine/dist/index.mjs
Can't import the named export 'Component' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

The currently installed versions in my system are node (v16.17.0), npm (8.19.2), react (18.2.0)

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Try installing it like this `npm install react-konva konva --save`

Comment: @monim Tried that as you suggested, still getting same error.